# Whats wrong in my php mysql counter script code?

Tags: php, mysql, counter

I am writing a Php 5 and Mysql 5 page counter script. When a student having id as 'visitorid' visits a page having id 'pageid' (both int(11)) the page counter tries to log the visit in 'visitors' database.  But counter is not updating in mysql db, instead the visit_counter int(4) turns to 0.Whats wrong with my code? visitdate is datetime.

```
<?php
 $pageid = 101;
 $visitorid = 234;

  $sql   = "SELECT *  FROM   visitors 
                      WHERE  pageid    = ".$pageid." 
                      AND    visitorid = ".$visitorid;

 $temp  = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error 1.<br>".mysql_error());
 $data  = mysql_fetch_array($temp);

 // visit_counter is a field in table
 if(($data['visit_counter']) != NULL){
 echo "Entery exists <br>";
 // Tried below version also
 $visit = " SET visit_counter  = visit_counter+1";

 //$visit_counter = $data['visit_counter'];
 //$visit = " SET visit_counter  = ".$visit_counter++ ;

// Valid SQL
// UPDATE `visitors` 
//      SET visit_counter = visit_counter+1 
//      WHERE pageid = 101 and visitorid=234
// This manual sql query updates in phpmyadmin

 $sql  = "UPDATE visitors  ".$visit."
           AND visitdate = NOW() 
           WHERE pageid    = ".$pageid." 
           AND   visitorid = ".$visitorid;

$temp = mysql_query($sql) or die("ERROR 3.<br>".mysql_error());
//No error is displayed on above query.

} else {
//first entry
$visit_count = "1";
$sql    = "INSERT INTO  visitors 
            (`pageid`,`visitorid`, `visitdate`, `visit_counter`)    
    VALUES ('".$pageid."','".$visitorid."', NOW(), '".$visit_count."')";
 $temp = mysql_query($sql);
 //first entry is inserted successfully 
 //and visit_counter shows 1 as entry.
}
?>
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I got answer by myself. Sometimes just little errors make us go crazy..
I made a mistake in udate query.. rather than using and I should have user a comma instead. .. working well now!